# Hibernate - delete childs when parent was deleted automatically with Annotations

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 entities, `Group` which has `User`s and is meant as `parent` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group implements Serializable{
//Some other content

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "group", 
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<User> users;
}
```

And child entity `User`, which has `Group` as parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable{
//other content

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private Group group;
```

The idea is when `Group` is deleted, all related `User`s also should be deleted. I created a unit test with in-memory database which shows what I mean:

```
@Test
public void test_WhenGroupIsRemoved_RelatedUsersAlsoShouldBeRemoved() throws Exception{
    service.save(new GroupDTO(null, "Group", (long)47));
    List<GroupDTO> groups = service.getAll();
    assertEquals(1, groups.size());

    GroupDTO groupDTO = groups.get(0);
    userService.save(new UserDTO(null, "testName", "testSurname", "testEmail", "333", groupDTO));
    userService.save(new UserDTO(null, "testName2", "testSurname2", "testEmail2", "333-2", groupDTO));
    service.delete(groupDTO);

    List<GroupDTO> emptyGroups = service.getAll();
    assertEquals(0, emptyGroups.size());
    List<UserDTO> emptyUsers = userService.getAll(new UserFilterParameters());
    assertEquals(0, emptyUsers.size());
}
```

But I can't remove `Group` with `User`s, because I get `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no action; FK_FM4CFGDT24TOH89YW4RBNU1LB table: USERS`.
SQL Code from console:

```
Hibernate: insert into groups (id, name) values (default, ?)
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.name as name2_0_0_ from groups this_
Hibernate: insert into users (id, email, group_id, name, phone, surname) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into users (id, email, group_id, name, phone, surname) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: delete from groups where id=?
```

Before `Hibernate: delete from groups where id=?` I think `User`s should be removed, I think it can be done automatically - with proper `Annotation` but I can't figure it out. If I remove `mappedBy = "group"` from `@OneToMany` side and add `@JoinColumn` (`Groups` entity) and add `@JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)` to `@ManyToOne` side (`User` entity) as I found in similar questions, I see some strange `ERROR: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10101 table: USERS column: GROUP_ID`.
I will be very happy if anybody decides to help me - thank you in advance!
**UPDATE** Service:

```
@Service
public class GroupServiceImpl implements GroupService {
@Autowired
private GroupDAO groupDAO;
@Autowired
private GroupTransformer groupTransformer;

@Override
@Transactional
public void delete(GroupDTO groupDTO) {
    groupDAO.delete(groupTransformer.dtoToEntity(groupDTO));
}
```

And there was a mistake: in `groupTransformer` transformation was simple, `return new Group(...)`. But it should be:

```
@Override
public Group dtoToEntity(GroupDTO groupDTO) {
    return groupDTO.getId() != null? dao.getById(groupDTO.getId()) : new Group(groupDTO.getId(), groupDTO.getName());
}
```

DAO should be used to get `Group` when DTO has Id (it means that it exists in database). Thanks to user @JB Nizet

Comment: I believe there is a `cascade` variable which you can set in the `@ManyToOne` annotation to something like `CASCADE.ALL`. Don't take my word for it though.

Comment: How is the service implemented?

Comment: @JB Nizet `Service` (more precisely, `Transformer`) was implemented in bad way. Thank you very much, your answer showed me the right way :)